# JS-Beautify programmatic options API

Tags: javascript, js-beautify

I am currently using this package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-beautify

like this:

```
import {js_beautify} from 'js-beautify';

const beautifiedCode = js_beautify(`
    const foo = 'bar';



    console.log(foo);
`)
```

however, imagine if I want to format the above, so that the maximum number of blank lines is one, so I want this:

```
  const foo = 'bar';

  console.log(foo);
```

unfortunately, I cannot find the docs on how to pass options to the programmatic API, I would guess it's something like this:

```
   const beautifiedCode = js_beautify(`
        const foo = 'bar';



        console.log(foo);
    `, 
     {maxBlankLines: 1}
    )
```

but that's just a guess. How can I pass options to the programmatic API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beautifier can remove blank lines between tokens using the `preserve_newlines: false` setting or limit the number of newlines using the `max_preserve_newlines` with a number value such as `max_preserve_newlines: 3`.

An example of API level usage is show in the [Javascript section of the project README.md](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify#javascript) .

The configuration option names are the same as the CLI names but with underscores instead of dashes.

So to remove all empty lines:

```
import {js_beautify} from 'js-beautify';

const originalCode = `
    const foo = 'bar';



    console.log(foo);
`)


const beautifiedCode = js_beautify(originalCode, { preserve_newlines: false});
```